# .htaccess redirect and add variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

our clients banner campain lauched today an the wrong url has been deposited.

So i try to redirect

```
website.com/wheels/?lang=en&sel=540
```

to

```
website.com/wheels/index.html?lang=en&sel=540
```

I tryed to put a .htaccess in the folder wheels which contains following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  index.html?lang=$1&sel=$2
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone has an idea, what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I found a existing .htaccess in the ROOT. It contains following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

If I add the code folling code, nothing happens:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en&sel=[0-9]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wheels)/$ /$1/index.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Btw, lang is not static, it can be en or de.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the .htaccess in the root directory of your website. The querystring parameters are carried through by default.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wheels/$  /wheels/index.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Yes, but this rule needs to go into the parent folder to wheels.  Also drop the leading / and the \, e.g. "wheels/index.html" (1) this is in a perdir context and (2) the substitution string is not a regexp so the "." doesn't need escaping

Comment: @TerryE You are correct about #2, so adjusted. Also agree that this should go in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your ROOT .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en&sel=[0-9]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wheels)/$ /$1/index.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by adding an extra RewriteCond in front of the existing RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond $0 !^wheels/
```